# Add null elements to non existing elements

Tags: java, arraylist, web-scraping, jsoup, web-crawler

I want to parse data from a webpage in the following divs:

I want to parse data from a webpage which can be provided the following:

```
<div class="InseratDaten">
    <div class="Art">Rent</div>
    <div class="Ort">TestCity 3., Roads Street</div>
    <div class="Preis"><span class='Label'>Miete:</span> 950 EUR</div>
    <div class="Groesse"><span class='Label'>Fläche:</span> 72 m²</div>
    <div class="Zimmer"><span class='Label'>Zimmer:</span> 3</div>
</div>
```

However, sometimes these structure looks totally different like:

```
<div class="InseratDaten">
    <div class="Art">Rent</div>
    <div class="Ort">Test 3., Road Street</div>
    <div class="Preis"><span class='Label'>Miete:</span> 919 EUR</div>
    <div class="Groesse"><span class='Label'>Fläche:</span> 84 m²</div>
    <div class="Zimmer"><span class='Label'>Zimmer:</span> 3</div>
    <div class="EigTitel">weitere Eigenschaften:</div>
    <div class='EigListe'>Shower, Balcony, Dog</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="InseratDaten">
    <div class="Art">Sale</div>
    <div class="Ort">Test 4., Road Street</div>
    <div class="Preis"><span class='Label'>Miete:</span> 919 EUR</div>
    <div class="Groesse"><span class='Label'>Fläche:</span> 84 m²</div>
</div>
```

As you can see the later code got expanded by the `<div class="EigTitel">` or some elements are missing.

At the moment I am parsing my data like that:

```
    if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
        HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
        String html = htmlParseData.getHtml();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
        Elements title = doc.select("div[class=Title]");
        Elements art = doc.select("div[class=Art]");
        Elements location = doc.select("div[class=Ort]");
        Elements price = doc.select("div[class=Preis]");
        Elements size = doc.select("div[class=Groesse]");
        Elements numberOfRooms = doc.select("div[class=Zimmer]");
        Elements furtherProperties = doc.select("div[class=EigListe]");

        /**
         * get each element as List
         */
        if (!(art.isEmpty()) && !(location.isEmpty()) && !(title.isEmpty()) && !(price.isEmpty())) {
            //iterate over art cause all elems have the same size
            titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
            artList = new ArrayList<String>();
            locationList = new ArrayList<String>();
            priceList = new ArrayList<String>();
            sizeList = new ArrayList<String>();
            numberOfRoomsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            furtherPropertiesList = new ArrayList<String>();

            //price
            for (Element element : price) {
                priceList.add(element.text().toString());
            }
            //size
            for (Element element : size) {
                sizeList.add(element.text().toString());
            }
            //numberOfRooms
            for (Element element : numberOfRooms) {
                numberOfRoomsList.add(element.text().toString());
            }
            //furtherProperties
            for (Element element : furtherProperties) {
                furtherPropertiesList.add(element.text().toString());
            }
            //location
            for (Element element : location) {
                locationList.add(element.text().toString());
            }   
            //art
            for (Element element : art) {
                artList.add(element.text().toString());
            }
            //title
            for (Element element : title) {
                titleList.add(element.text().toString());
            }

            log.info(ListstoString());

            //add everything to the main domain List
            for (int i = 0; i < locationList.size(); i++) {
                Property prop = new Property();
                //price
                prop.setPrice(priceList.get(i));
                //size
                prop.setSize(sizeList.get(i));
                //number of rooms
                prop.setNumberOfRooms(numberOfRoomsList.get(i));
                //furtherProperties
                prop.setFurtherProperties(furtherPropertiesList.get(i));
                //location
                prop.setLocation(locationList.get(i));
                //art
                prop.setTransactionType(artList.get(i));
                //title
                prop.setTitle(titleList.get(i));
                //set date
                prop.setCrawlingDate(new Date());
                list.add(prop);
            }
            log.info(list.toString());
   }
}
```

My problem is that in some cases my lists can be differently long, because data can be missing and therefore I am getting an error:

`[sizeList=16, priceList=16, locationList=16, numberOfRoomsList=12, furtherPropertiesList=12]`

I would like to put null elements where a div has no such attributes to keep my data consistent. I guess this has sth to do with jsoup to put null elements there? Any idea to implement that?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score -1):

You can create your lists of a predefined size like:

```
titleList = Arrays.asList(new String[locationList.size()]);
```

and then use the index when setting elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < title.size(); i++) {
  titleList.set(i, title.get(i).text().toString());
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, I guess I am losing the order of the elements when doing that? How could I set not available elements just `null`?